# How to count element X in Data Frame 1 in Data Frame 2

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames in R:

DataFrame 1 has two columns: MAC_Address and Manufacture
This data frame has about 4000 rows, where each row is different MAC and Manufacture.

DataFrame 2 has one column: MAC_Addressess
This data frame has about 300 rows, and the same MAC can be found in multiple rows.

What I am dealing with is, how can I count how often one Manufactures MAC from Dataframe1 is found in DataFrame 2?

This a simple example, not the correct MACs by the way.

```
Scanning <- data.frame (MAC  = c("EE-16-17", "EE-16-17",  "AE-04-80", "EE-16-17", "FA-53-17"))

OUI <- data.frame (MAC  = c("EE-16-17", "FA-53-17", "FA-B3-17"),
                  Manufacturer = c("Intel", "Apple", "Microsoft"))
```

So I would get a result like this, hopefully in another data frame, which I could then sort by frequency:

```
Intel: 3
Apple: 1
Microsoft: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be :

```
merge(data.frame(table(Scanning)),OUI,by="MAC",all.y=T) %>% 
  replace_na(list(Freq=0))
```

First you count the occurence of each model with `table` in `Scanning`, then you `merge` the result with the table containing brands. Finally, you can replace the NA values by 0.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Scanning %>%
  # for each `MAC`...:
  group_by(MAC) %>%
  # ... count how often it occurs:
  summarise(N = n()) %>%
  # join `OUI` with the result:
  left_join(OUI, .) %>% 
  # convert NA into 0:
  mutate(N = replace_na(N, 0))
       MAC Manufacturer  N
1 EE-16-17        Intel  3
2 FA-53-17        Apple  1
3 FA-B3-17    Microsoft  0
```

Comment: Small addition: note the tidyr dependency (tidyr::replace_na)

Answer (score 0):

with `dplyr`:

EDIT: I did't read it right the first time. This should work:

```r
Scanning %>% 
  count(MAC, sort = TRUE) %>% 
  left_join(OUI, .) %>% 
  mutate(n = ifelse(is.na(n),0, n))
#    MAC       Manufacturer n
# 1  EE-16-17  Intel        3
# 2  FA-53-17  Apple        1
# 3  FA-B3-17  Microsoft    0
```

Comment: No, there Microsoft gets one count, but it actually has no match in the Scanning list. So Microsoft = 0

Comment: You were right, I read it too quickly. The edit should work though. It is somewhat similar to Chris Ruehlemann's answer though